# wp_delete_attachment not working with multiple values

Tags: php, uploads, media

I'm using an `<input>` tag that stores the values of multiple attachment image ids and it's not working.

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

```
<input type="hidden" name="jfiler-items-exclude-imgid" value="["4602","4603"]">
if (isset($_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid'])) {
    $att_ids = $_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid'];
    $att_id = explode(',', $att_ids);
    foreach ($att_id as $atts_id){
        wp_delete_attachment($att_ids);
}
```

Comment: please dump $_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid'] to see what you get? e.g. var_dump( $_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid'] ); please put the output in your edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$att_ids = explode(',', $_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid'])), will return a key=>value array, so you must write your foreach loop to handle keys and values

```
foreach($att_ids as $key=>$att_id){
    wp_delete_attachment($att_id);
}
```

Comment: You'r right but still not delete attachment images

Comment: Array ( [0] => [\"4600\" [1] => \"4599\"] ) getting this array

Comment: To not use str_replace, you can change your input : `<input type="hidden" name="jfiler-items-exclude-imgid" value="["4602","4603"]">` can be `<input type="hidden" name jfiler-items-exclude-imgid[] value="4602"/><input type="hidden" name jfiler-items-exclude-imgid[] value="4603"/>` . But, it's another question !

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/CreativeDream/jQuery.filer for uploading and deleting and in this i can't use you'r method if you have way so i can use sharing complete post-edit file with you

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzEC95TzCVWpOFJ4eWVfUEpMVGs/view?usp=sharing check post edit file

Comment: You can also try to json_decode the posted value before exploding it. As it it look like a json string, it can make the trick.

Comment: did you mean this method http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php  ...?

Comment: Yes, just change your code to i.e: `$posted_string = json_decode($_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid']);`, you'll get an object, convert it to array with (array) $posted_string.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the help of @Benoti

```
    if (isset($_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid'])) {
        $string = str_replace('"', '', $_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid']);
        $string1 = str_replace('\\', '', $string); 
        $string3 = str_replace('[', '', $string1);
        $string4 = str_replace(']', '', $string3);
        $att_ids = explode(',', $string4);
        foreach($att_ids as $key=>$att_id){
                wp_delete_attachment($att_id);
            }
    }
```